# Append groups of images based on their total sizes

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have hundreds of images named in this pattern:

```
file-001.gif
file-002.gif
file-003.gif
...
```

Using, magick, I want to append every group of images with the condition that they don't exceed 950kb in their total size.

Then process the next batch while they are less than 950kb in total as well, and so on.

Is it possible to that in a shell script?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, it is not quite clear what you mean by "_append_ every group of images". Could you edit your post to explain in more detail what you want to achieve?

Comment: You have your answer. Did you mean 950 kb as in "kilobits" (950,000 bits), or did you really want to write 950 kB as in "950,000 bytes"?

Answer (score -1):

If you need your batch-appended images to end up inside objects smaller than 950kB, then no single image file can be more than that same cutoff size.
**First step**: list all such files along with their size in bytes:

```
$ find -L /path/to/directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.gif" -size -950k \
 -exec sh -c '\ls -Lgo "$1" | tr -s " "  | cut "-d " -f3,7-' sh {} \;
```

This will print the names of all found files and their respective size on screen, one to a line, listed in the order they were found. Main flags for `find` are:

- `-L`: follow symbolic links and present info about the target of the link, not about the link itself. If you don't want that, use `-H` instead.
- `-maxdepth 1`: make search descend at most **`1`** level, down from `/path/to/directory`. Modify number as you wish. See `man find` for more info.

Note that at least on my `bash` 5.0 implementation, `find` seems to function with kibibytes (kiB). In other words the above will find files which are less than or equal in size to 950*1024 bytes. 
If you insist on 950 kilobytes (950000 B) being your cutoff size, no problem: just use `-size 927730c` instead. On Debian distros this seems to have been solved back in 2016 already, so you can go ahead and use `-size 950k`...

*"Size"* can be an ambiguous property.  For lack of more info in OP, I also include the fact that you could use *total allocated block size* for each discovered file. If that's what you want/need, then do:

```
$ find -L /path/to/directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.gif" -size -950k \
  -exec sh -c '\ls -Ls -C1 "$1"' sh {} \;
```

The size numbers you will get from that will depend on the block size of your storage medium.

**Second step**: process previous output with `magick` by means of a shell script `batch_append.sh`, in one pass. Append image files in the order listed, subject to the condition that no resulting objects should weigh more than 950kB. The output of the `find` command is used to populate an array like so:

```
$ cat batch_append.sh

#!/usr/bin/bash

sdir=/path/to/directory
size=0
nas_idx=0    # next append start (nas) index (idx)
cnt=0
declare -a b

IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -a a < <(find -L "$sdir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.gif" -size -950k -exec sh -c '\ls -Lgo "$1" | tr -s " " | cut "-d " -f3,7-' sh {} \; 2>/dev/null)
num=${#a[@]}

for (( i=0; i<num; i++ )); do
    (( size+=$(echo "${a[$i]}" | cut "-d " -f1) ))

    if [ "$size" -gt 950000 ] ; then
        (( size-=$(echo "${a[$i]}" | cut "-d " -f1) ))
        (( i-=1 ))
        #echo "$size" for files from "$(( nas_idx+1 ))" to "$(( i+1 ))"  # testing
        #echo "${b[@]}"   # testing
        magick "${b[@]}" append appended_$(( nas_idx+1 ))_$(( i+1 )).gif
        nas_idx=$(( i+1 ))
        size=0  # reset 'size' variable to start new append batch
        cnt=0
        unset b
    else
        b[cnt]=$(echo "${a[$i]}" | cut "-d " -f2-)
        (( cnt++ ))
    fi

    if (( i==num-1 )); then
        # last append batch
        #echo "$size" for files from "$(( nas_idx+1 ))" to "$(( i+1 ))"  # testing
        #echo "${b[@]}"   # testing
        magick "${b[@]}" append appended_$(( nas_idx+1 ))_$(( i+1 )).gif
        unset b
    fi
done

printf '\n  %d files were processed.\n' "$num"
exit(0)
```

---

Closing remarks:

- Make the script executable before running it. `chmod ug+x batch_append.sh`
- You need to run the script only once.
- That script was not fully tested with `magick`.
- For a production environment, a number of traps ought to be included.
- The script can be improved, perhaps by arranging for parallel execution if your host has several cores and a lot of files to process.
- Files are batch-processed as they come, i.e. as the `find` cmd stats them. This will depend on a number of search flags and on how you order then in the `find` one-liner.

Comment: i guess that does not answer the question since i read it as that the files should be no more than 950k in size summed so file1=100k file2=400k file3=400k file4=50k would be a scenario that would fit the bill which your answer does not acomplish... its not my downvote though and the question is written quite lacky tbh

Answer (score -1):

Ok I am pretty confident that this is the most badass oneliner I ever came across but I guess it will do it.
Loosely based on https://askubuntu.com/questions/878948/how-do-i-generate-a-running-cumulative-total-of-the-numbers-in-a-text-file

```
sed $(echo 3+`ls -la | tee out/filesWithSizes.txt | awk '{print $5}' | awk '{total += $0; $0 = total}1' | sed 's/$/ < 950000/' | bc | grep -o '1' | wc -l`|bc )q out/filesWithSizes.txt | tail -n +4
```

Let me explain this madness:

Use `ls -la` to get all files with their sizes

Use `tee` to store that information away for future reference and keep it in the pipe

Use `awk` to print the 5th column (i.e. the size)

Use more `awk` to generate a cumulative sum thereof which is per design guaranteed to be sorted (that gets important later on)

Use `sed` to replace the end of the line with `< 950000` so basically append that string

Use `bc` to evaluate those expressions and turn them into boolean values (ie 0 or 1)

Use `grep -o` to only print the lines with 1

since the cumulative sum is per design sorted the output thereof can be counted and you know the number of files (in order) that can be pasted together

This part is done with `wc -l`. Since I did not get things working without the a flag in the initial `ls` I echo 3+the-number-we-just-calculated into `bc` to get the stopping point for the output of the list of files

Then use `sed` with command substitution to quit outputing the contents of the list of files with their sizes we safed before after the number of lines we just calculated with that echo thing

Lastly use `tail` to start outputing at the first non header line of said file.

This gets you a list of all files that can be stitched together. You just have to make sure that you move away all the files that you already processed and rerun that hefty oneliner over and over again until there are no files anymore in your directory...